# OSM-> longitude and latitude SQL

Tags: openstreetmap

i want to extract postal code, town,city,village,longtitude and latitude for it.

already know how to extract postal_code, zip,name,place.... i know it can be complicated, but what i need is only just lon and lat for each town.
something like you have on wikipedia: Coordinates   48°08′38″N 17°06′35″E

```
    select  tags->'postal_code' as zip, name, place, 
    from planet_osm_point 
    where place IN('hamlet', 'village', 'town') 
    order by zip;
```

this is what i came up with.

Comment: What are you using for querying? PostGIS?

Comment: Do you have OSM data already loaded into your Postgres database (with osm2pgsql or similar)? Do you have the PostGIS extension installed on your database? It's not very clear to me what kind of data you are working exactly, but I guess you have all this because you are using `planet_osm_point`